# Unable to add RELEASE DATE on new Movie object in the Movies Array (Java)

Tags: java, date, parsing

Need your help in my Java assignment. I've tried multiple ways but I am still unable to add a Release Date info for a new Movie (with some exception handling). It is not parsing correctly. Then I tried to add "new Date" on the Movie array constructor, it's generating a random date.

Please see code below:

```java
//Creates the new film Object to be inserted into the array
        Movie addMovie = new Movie(0,"","",new Date(),0,0);
```

NOTE: NEW MOVIE is has this format matching above: `(int MovieID, String Title, String genre, Date Release Date, int duration, int cost)`

```java
//CODE SNIPPET only for adding RELEASE DATE for new MOVIE:
        //set DATE - DATE
System.out.println("Please enter RELEASE DATE: ");
SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd");
addFilm.setReleaseDate(input.nextLine(ft.parse);


//        //throws exception for invalid date
if(addFilm.getReleaseDate().before(1893-12-22) || addFilm.getReleaseDate().after(2019-12-25) {
throw new Exception("Please enter a film release date older that the film industry or sometime in the future!");
}
input.nextLine();
```

Any thoughts what am I missing here?

Comment: Consider providing a [mcve]

Comment: You should drop `Date` and use `LocalDate`, as the former will get you it trouble.

Answer (score 1):

## Faulty field name

One specific problem is that you improperly named the member field of your custom class.

You said your class definition included:

```
… , Date Release Date, …
```

Field and variable names in Java must be a single word, with no spaces. Your name “Release Date” violates that rule.

Also, that name violates the Java naming convention of starting field and var names with a lowercase letter.

Correct naming:

```
… , Date releaseDate, …
```

Or more simply:

```
… , Date released, …
```

## Faulty literals

You also have some faulty code where you passed what you thought was a literal form of a date value, but was actually integer literals with arithmetic.

```
.before(1893-12-22)
```

There in that line you passed the `int` value of 1,859. That is the result of starting with 1,893 and then subtracting two numbers, twelve and twenty-two. That number you passed was interpreted as a specified number of milliseconds since the standard base time known as "the epoch", namely January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.

But more importantly, you should never be using the class `Date` nor `SimpleDateFormat`.

## *java.time*

You are using terrible date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

For a date-only value without time of day and without time zone, use `LocalDate`. Instantiate immutable objects of that type by calling the static factory methods such as `of`.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2022 , Month.MAY , 23 ) ;
```

Let’s take your movies example.

```
record Movie( String title , LocalDate released ) {}
List< Movie > movies = 
    List.of(
        new Movie( "Gone With The Wind" , LocalDate.of( 1939, 12 , 15 ) ) , 
        new Movie( "Purple Rain" , LocalDate.of( 1984, 7 , 27 ) ) 
    ) ;
```